# Parity of the number of '1's in subsets of the coefficients of irreducible polynomials of degree $n$ over $GF(2)$

Tags: reference-request, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

Let $n > 2$ and let $S \subsetneq [n-1] = \{1, \ldots, n-1\}$. Has it been proven whether or not we can always find an irreducible polynomial $f(x)$ of degree $n$ over the binary field $GF(2)$ such that it has exactly an odd (even) number of $s \in S$ for which $[x^s] f(x) = 1$?

I am aware there are open conjectures regarding existence of primitive (irreducible) polynomials  with several prescribed coefficients over GF(2), but I haven't seen anything regarding the parity of the prescribed set. In any case this should be a much weaker conjecture than these, but I wonder if anyone could refer me to previous work on this?

Comment: for the even case a polynomial with those properties is always reducible

Comment: Not necessarily since $S$ is a proper subset of $[n+1]$

Comment: Ok I misunderstood the question. My answer was in the case when $S=[n-1]$.

Comment: What's the meaning of the notation $[x]^s f(x)$?

Comment: Anyway, the problem of estimating the number of irreducible polynomials with a specified sequence of high degree terms, low degree terms, or a combination of both, is an analogue of the asymptotic equidistribution of prime numbers into (coprime) residue classes modulo $m$. The asymptotic theory is described in [Michael Rosen's book](http://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387953359). Several cases have been calculated explicitly.

Comment: Thanks. $[x^s]f(x)$ is a funky notation for the coefficient of $x^s$ in $f(x)$. I've seen a bit of literature on what you mentioned. There are several papers on this using the analogy on function fields of Dirichlet's theorem for primes in arithmetic progressions. They seem to have hit a wall on this area since most of their estimates revolve around using Weil's bound, which means that the number of coefficients they can prescribe is about $n/2$, when the degree is $n$. For larger $S$ there seems to be only few results. .

Comment: Thus I wondered whether they have at least proved weaker results, such as the parity of the coefficients of $x^s$ for $s \in S$ when $S$ is large (say $|S| > n/2$)

Comment: This in contrast seems like a much weaker problem, since there are $2^{|S| - 1}$ ways of getting the desired parity in $S$. My bet is that this is a decades old/folklore type result. But I haven't seen this anywhere. Anyway it seems like a natural problem